# How do you prevent 'react-scripts build' from minifying certain pieces of code?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, build

Setup: node react app with TurnstoneSearch plugin

So the issue is that when I run

```
npm run build
```

it breaks the functionality of my searchbar in my app. I figure it is because during the webpack minification process that

```
react-scripts build
```

broke turnstone's functionality somehow.

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way I can just stop the turnstone code from minifying so that it functions properly.

I tried to look into the webpack script that is invoked, but I don't know where to begin. There is a method to turn off *all* minification but that defeats the purpose of building for production...

Comment: How is broken exactly? Depending on what the issue is there's several reasons for differences in prod vs dev. I seriously doubt it's the minifier, the whole point of that is just to shorten _without_ changing any functionality. I'd investigate the specific problem more closely

Comment: The searchbox makes a query to an api based on every keypress for an autofill box. I can see that the GET /api calls are made successfully in the logging, but the autofill box isn't working like it does in development. It doesn't render at all.

Comment: Does your code work if you turn off all minification in production?